# CSV Uploader - mapping multiple columns into single property

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have a CSV (no header) ..:

```
Electronics, Computer, Laptop, Small, Fast, New
Electronics, Computer, Desktop, Medium, Slow, Old
...
```

and need to upload multiple CSV columns as a single property

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file://foo.csv" AS line
foreach (x in range(3,length(line)-2) | 
//some other stuff...
merge (s:T {word: line[x], describing: line[1], path: line[1..x]}
```

And I will have to query each node later via the path property:

```
Match (n:T) where n.path = "Computer, Desktop, Medium, Slow, Old"...
```

The trouble is, the CSV uploader encodes collections, `line[1..x]` with everything quoted:

```
path property
["Computer", "Desktop", "Medium", "Slow", "Old"]
```

and so the above query would come up empty. Is there a way to upload multiple CSV columns into a single String property?

Comment: I would create an actual graph structure of your tree, that's what a graph database is all about.

Comment: I do indeed have a graph structure -- the graph is a big ontology with each word being a node, . Im only using the "path" as a unique identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `line[1..x]` with:

```
REDUCE(s = "", y IN line[1..x] | s + (
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(s) = 0
    THEN ""
    ELSE ", "
  END) + y)
```

That should generate a single comma-delimited string instead of an array of strings.

Comment: ah yes, use an accumulator. very nice solution